# Why not to use Kubernetes StatefulSet for stateless applications?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment, statefulset

I know why use StatefulSet for stateful applications. (e.g. DB or something)
In most cases, I can see like "You want to deploy stateful app to k8s? Use StatefulSet!"
However, I couldn't see like "You want to deploy stateless app to k8s? Then, DO NOT USE StatefulSet" ever.

Even nobody says "I don't recommend to use StatefulSet for stateless app", many stateless apps is deployed through Deployment, like it is the standard.

The StatefulSet has clear pros for stateful app, but I think Deployment doesn't for stateless app.
Is there any pros in Deployment for stateless apps? Or is there any clear cons in StatefulSet for stateless apps?

I supposed that StatefulSet cannot use LoadBalancer Service or StatefulSet has penalty to use HPA, but all these are wrong.

I'm really curious about this question.

P.S. Precondition is the stateless app also uses the PV, but not persists stateful data, for example logs.

I googled "When not to use StatefulSet", "when Deployment is better than StatefulSet", "Why Deployment is used for stateless apps", or something more questions.

I also see the k8s docs about StatefulSet either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Different Priorities

What happens when a Node becomes unreachable in a cluster?

### Deployment - Stateless apps

You want to maximize availability. As soon as Kubernetes detects that there are fewer than the desired number of replicas running in your cluster, the controllers spawn new replicas of it. Since these apps are stateless, it is very easy to do for the Kubernetes controllers.

### StatefulSet - Stateful apps

You want to maximize availability - but not you must ensure **data consistency** (the state). To ensure *data consistency*, each replica has its own unique ID, and there are never multiple replicas of this ID, e.g. it is unique. This means that you cannot spawn up a new replica, unless that you are sure that the replica on the unreachable Node are terminated (e.g. stops using the Persistent Volume).

#### Conclusion

Both Deployment and StatefulSet try to maximize the availability - but StatefulSet cannot sacrifice **data consistency** (e.g. your state), so it cannot act as fast as Deployment (stateless) apps can.

These priorities does not only happens when a Node becomes unreachable, but at all times, e.g. also during upgrades and deployments.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to a Kubernetes Deployment, where pods are easily replaceable, each pod in a StatefulSet is given a name and treated individually. Pods with distinct identities are necessary for stateful applications.

This implies that if any pod perishes, it will be apparent right away. StatefulSets act as controllers but do not generate ReplicaSets; rather, they generate pods with distinctive names that follow a predefined pattern. The ordinal index appears in the DNS name of a pod. A distinct persistent volume claim (PVC) is created for each pod, and each replica in a StatefulSet has its own state.

For instance, a StatefulSet with four replicas generates four pods, each of which has its own volume, or four PVCs. StatefulSets require a headless service to return the IPs of the associated pods and enable direct interaction with them. The headless service has a service IP but no IP address and has to be created separately.The major components of a StatefulSet are the set itself, the persistent volume and the headless service.

That all being said, people deploy Stateful Applications with Deployments, usually they mount a RWX PV into the pods so all "frontends" share the same backend. Quite common in CNCF projects.

Answer (score 0):

A stateful set manages each POD with a unique **hostname** based on an **index** number. So with an **index**, it would be easy to **identify** the individual PODs and also easy for the application to check which on **rely** or **unique network identities**. Also, you might have read stateful sets get **deleted** in a specified order to maintain consistency.

When you use stateful for the stateless application it will be like a burden to manage and add complexity to **unique network identities** and **ordering** guarantees.

For example, when you scale down to zero stateful sets it goes in the controlled way while with **deployment** or **RS** it won't be the same case. However, there is no guarantee when deleting the resource stateful set.

Also, Before a scaling operation is applied to a stateful set **Pod**, all of its predecessors must be **Running and Ready**. So if you are deploying the **application**, three Pods will be deployed suppose in order app-0, app-1, app-2. **app-1** wont be deployed before **app-0** is Running & Ready, and app-2 wont be deployed until **app-1** is Ready.

While with deployment you can manage the **%** for and handle the **RollingUpdate** scenario but with a **stateful set** it will **delete** and **recreate** new POD **one by one**.